# Getting PDOException while trying to use a Pager in a Query

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, pager

I am using Drupal 7 and i want to use the Pager into my query

This is my query and the way I can use

```
$query = db_select("SELECT entity_id , field_keywords_value , COUNT( DISTINCT ( entity_id )) total FROM field_data_field_keywords WHERE bundle = 'song' GROUP BY field_keywords_value");

$query = $query -> extend('PagerDefault'); 
$result = $query -> extend('PagerDefault') ->limit(2) ->execute();
```

but it give me the error, PDOException: erro

And if I can use it in the following way:

```
$query = db_query("SELECT entity_id , field_keywords_value , COUNT( DISTINCT ( entity_id )) total FROM field_data_field_keywords WHERE bundle = 'song' GROUP BY field_keywords_value"); 
$query = $query -> extend('PagerDefault'); 
$result = $query ->extend('PagerDefault') ->limit(2) ->execute(); echo ""; print_r($result); die('tert');
```

Then my page not working and give me the blank page.

Any help will be appreciate.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have resolved the problem by my self
    $query = db_select('field_data_field_keywords')->extend('PagerDefault');
        $query->fields('field_data_field_keywords', array('field_keywords_value', 'entity_id'));
        $query->condition('bundle', 'song');
        $query->condition('field_keywords_value', arg(2));
        $query->distinct(entity_id);
         $result = $query
                ->limit(1)
                ->execute()
                ->fetchAll();

thanks

Comment: You should mark your question as answered, so it doesn't show up in the "Unaswered" list.